# Google Appmaker selectedRow

Tags: google-app-maker

On a Google appmaker `table`, I have a `label` that I only want `visible` when the row is active/selected by the user.

I can see that the `datasource.itemtIndex` would give me the current index that my label is at (I presume it's not the selected index), but I can not seem to find a property that shows me the currently selected index/row.

Comment: Little bit off your original question... you can try Accordion widget. It provides details section, that is visible only when the row is selected.

Answer (score 2):

Bind the visibility of the label like this ==>

```javascript
@widget.datasource.item._key === @datasources.<DatasourceName>.item._key
```

Just make sure to change `<DatasourceName>` with whatever datasource you're using.

Comment: Alternatively the binding can look like this: `@widget.datasource.item._key === @widget.parent.parent.datasource.item._key` (first parent is row, second parent is list itself)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this style

```
visibleOnAncestorHover
```

to the label styles. This should make it visible both on hover and when selected. (This is used by default on Table widget's row delete buttons, I think.)

EDIT: and remember to have the 'visible' setting on for the label.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found to do this is to set the visible binding on your label, of course you would want to set your visibility type to absent (will mis-align your table rows to labels) or hidden (will just hide the label). This solution is different from the 'visibleOnAncestorHover' as the label will still be hidden on other rows when you hover on those rows, it is only visible when the row is actually selected. The only binding that seems to work is this:

@datasources.YourDatasource.itemIndex === @widget.parent.childIndex

The following apparently does NOT work:

@datasource.itemIndex === @widget.parent.childIndex

or

@widget.datasource.itemIndex === @widget.parent.childIndex

Please see the picture below:
[image: App Maker Table with visible label on selected row]

Answer (score 1):

You can specify this in the style editor:

```
.app-NewPage-Table1Row:not(.selected) .app-NewPage-Field2 {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```