# How to show icon buttons only on selection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I have created a page with a table widget which contains icon buttons that are connected to an edit page and a review page.
[image: the widget]
I would prevent App Maker from displaying the buttons permanently. The buttons should only be shown for a selected record. Is there a way to do this in CSS or do I have to add a hide/unhide script to the onclick-event of the record? I would also like to know how I can format the date in the record as dd/mm/yyyy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following built-in App Maker CSS class to the button:
`visibleOnAncestorHover`. You can reverse-engineer how the delete button is implemented:

[image: CSS style]

Comment: Pavel, I have another question: Is it possible to make the buttons only visible if the row has been clicked on?

Comment: So, you don't want to see icon on mouse hover, but only if the row is selected, right?

Comment: That'is correct. I have a few buttons that depend on the selection.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46868881/454137 - will this work for you? (*note* most likely you will need to discard any prior changes)